# PHP Transform query by nesting results in columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table

I have the following result from a query.

[image: Query result]

I'm trying to transform the result of the above query into:

```
Parcelas |   A   |    D   |
2        | 65.99 |  47.99 |
3        | 66.19 |  48.19 |
4        | 66.39 |  48.39 |
5        | 66.59 |  48.59 |
...
```

Can anyone give me an idea on how to do it?

I tried to go through it with a foreach and check if this value already exists in an array and if it has to be incremented with another array.

Help me please

Comment: It's not helpful, Can you give us a pattern based on columns name ?

Comment: Maybe a PIVOT query would help you

Comment: Well, you can use query for that.. could share your query ? if you're using these results somewhere else so I suggest [collection groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby) , you  can group by id then a map that will be easy

Comment: There are many solutions posted already. Search for the combination of tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot-table

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this in the database query.  However, if that's not an option and you need to rearrange the data in PHP, something like this pattern may be what you need:

```
$results = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAssoc()) {
  if (!isset($results[$row['parcelas']])) {
    $results[$row['parcelas']] = [];
  }
  $results[$row['parcelas']][$row['nome']] = $row['cet'];
}

print_r($results);
```

If you do have access to changing the query, this might work for you:

```
SELECT
  parcelas,
  SUM(IF(tabela.nome = "A", cet, null)) AS A,
  SUM(IF(tabela.nome = "B", cet, null)) AS B
FROM parcela
INNER JOIN tabela ON tabela.id = parcela.tabela_id
WHERE tabela.id IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY parcelas
```

Comment: And how to stay in SQL?

My query code is:

SELECT parcelas, cet, tabela_id, tabela.nome
FROM parcela
INNER JOIN tabela ON tabela.id=parcela.tabela_id
where tabela_id in (1,4)
group by tabela_id, parcelas, cet
order by parcelas, tabela.nome

Comment: I added a suggestion about doing this in the query